# JDBC Spring 4 NamedParameterJdbcTemplate with enum

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

I have been using `JdbcTemplate` very happyly but then I got convinced to use `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`. However not enjoying this so far sometimes or all the times.

Lets say I have a Person class as below :

```
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private int age;
    private String name;
    private long socialId;
    private Gender gender;
    private String email;

    enum Gender {
        MALE, FEMALE
    }

}
```

And I am trying to insert the list of person as below:

```
SqlParameterSource[] params 
= SqlParameterSourceUtils.createBatch(personList.toArray());

            getNamedJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(insertSql, params);
```

However it fails with message below

```
PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [INSERT INTO

at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setObject(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:230)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setObject(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:169)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setObject(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:169)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:402)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:235)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:166)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.BatchUpdateUtils.setStatementParameters(BatchUpdateUtils.java:65)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.access$000(NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.java:32)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils$1.setValues(NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.java:48)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:999)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:989)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:644)
    ... 41 more
```

I debugged and can see that in `StatementCreatorUtils` class it will always fail if it is of Enum type in method

```
private static void setValue(PreparedStatement ps, int paramIndex
```

section of code....

```
else if (sqlType == SqlTypeValue.TYPE_UNKNOWN) {
            if (isStringValue(inValue.getClass())) {
                ps.setString(paramIndex, inValue.toString());
            }
```

**QUESTION**

Can someone please let me know any workaround for this? Or I need to do old way of setting data using placeholders( ?).

Many thanks

Answer (score 7):

Got this working as below

```
sqlParameterSource.registerSqlType("gender", Types.VARCHAR);
```

This is fine but WHAT if we need to call a method on enum. Let's say getValue for enums like Male(10), FEMALE( 20)??

I am not able to use these enums very well with `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`

Anyone looking to improve this in future?

Thanks

Comment: thanks, resolved my issue. Also, did you happen to find any other solution?

Answer (score 4):

The `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` accepts SQL with placeholders using nested properties/methods. I don't see that in the documentation, but you can use something like:

```
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(
       "INSERT INTO mytable " +
       "(myVarcharColumn, myIntColumn) " +
       "VALUES (:myEnum1.name, :myEnum2.ordinal)", 
       batchArgs);
```